# I've been trying to run this paddleocr code but it keeps on saying result is undefined even though it's already been defined in the first line

Tags: python, undefined, paddleocr

```py
%timeit  result = ocr.ocr(img_path, cls =True)
for line in result:
  print(line)
```

I couldn't figure anything out as I do not understand what is wrong with it

Comment: Posted the wrong bit of code, this is what's bothering me:

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)